# When I merge namespaces with classes, typescript reminded me to no-redeclare

Tags: typescript

I'm coding based on the [documents here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes-functions-and-enums). Why is this a problem?

Is this typescript's mistake?

```js
class BST {
    root:BST.Node
    constructor (key:number, value:any) {
      this.root = new BST.Node(key, value)
    }
}
// error: 'BST' is already defined.
namespace BST{
    export class Node {
        key:number
        value:any
        constructor (key:number, value:any) {
          this.key = key
          this.value = value
        }
    }
}
export {
  BST
}
```

There's another problem. How should I write `root` type?

```js
class BST {
    // How should I write `root` type?
    root: ???;
    constructor (key:number, value:any) {
      this.root = new BST.Node(key, value)
    }

    static Node = class Node {
        key:number
        value:any
        constructor (key:number, value:any) {
          this.key = key
          this.value = value
        }
    }
}

export {
  BST
}
```

Comment: I [can't reproduce this error](https://tsplay.dev/w6Bnyw); can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue when dropped into a standalone IDE?  Or, barring that, a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates your issue?  Otherwise you might need to start describing your project configuration in great detail and hope someone else can find what the issue is from that.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I didn't write in enough detail. The problem is that `typescript-esLint. and `typescript` in conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from @typescript-esLint.

I found it when I checked the github QA.

↓

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code

↓

[I am using a rule from ESLint core, and it doesn't work correctly with TypeScript code.](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code)

↓

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-redeclare.md

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'standard'
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  rules: {
    // answer
    'no-redeclare': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare': ['error']
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.